# Maven2: Possible to deploy depends on artifact classifier?

Tags: maven-2, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

In fact I have 2 different problems, but I think they are kind of related:

1. I have an artifact, with an assembly descriptor set which will build an extra JAR (with extra classifier).  By default, Maven2/3 will deploy the assembly generated together with the main artifact to remove Maven repository.  Is there any way that I can deploy only the main artifact but not the assembly?
2. I have an artifact, in which I have jar plugin generate another artifact with different classifier (more specific, an EJB artifact, and I generate an client JAR).  I want to deploy only the client JAR to Maven repo coz I think the main EJB artifact is not really going to be shared by other project.  Is it possible to do so?

Thanks a lot

---

editied to provide more info:

The reason for avoiding deploy the EJB, is because the EJB main artifact is not going to be depended by other project except the containing project.  The containing project will build a EAR (which contains the EJB), and normally we only need that build locally (by mvn package).  However, the EJB client is something that we will deploy to our repo to let other project share when they need to communicate with our application.

Honestly it doesn't harm to deploy the EJB too, but I just want to see if I can save unnecessary waste of disk space on our repository.

Similarly, for deploying assembly, it is because the project is something we want to deploy to let other project to depends on.  However, when building that project, we also have a separate assembly created on the same time (for example, an all-in-one executable jar) which we only need that built locally, and it is not something that other projects will depends on.

Comment: Why would you like to prevent deploying the main EJB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off the 'attach' option to the assembly plugin. Then it won't be officially an artifact and it won't deploy; it will just lurk in the target directory, sulking that you don't love it as much as it's elder sibling and plot revenge.

Comment: Although this only serve for half of the behavior (avoid assembly being deployed), it seems to me that there is no way to control deployment base on classifier.  This solution at least serve for one of the case I am looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: I think that you are correct that the deploy plugin cannot be controlled in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your first question i would like to know why do you create the supplemental assembly which is usually deployed as well as the main artifact. If you wan't to prevent you can put the creation of the assembly into a profile but this means you will not generate the supplemental artifact in your usual build only by activating the profile.